# How to filter packets sent by dns.lookup in Wireshark on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, dns, wireshark, getaddrinfo

To give some context: we're monitoring the network connectivity in our app by calling nodeJS `dsn.lookup` within an interval. Some of our users are facing issues with this technique. So I'd like to inspect what's going on when degrading the network connectivity with a tool like [clumsy](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/) .

Before debugging the app, I 'd rather like to ensure clumsy is doing a proper job (when playing with the packet drop feature for example) and want to inspect the packets in Wireshark.

What filter should I apply to filter the packets I am interested in?

Reading at [the documentation of dns.lookup](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_lookup_hostname_options_callback), it seems that the method as nothing to do with a real dns request and under the hood, it's using the system getaddrinfo implementation. Unfortunately, this does not really help me to figure out a proper filter in Wireshark. I even feel that somehow, the request aren't even captured, since I did a global search with the ip and the hostname I am performing the lookup against.

Comment: `getaddrinfo` may or may not result in DNS queries, depending on how `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is configured; also note that names in DNS queries can be compressed and hence difficult to grep, except of course if the tool you are using to see DNS packets is able to decompress them and print them correctly.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this question is related to a Windows environnement (no nsswitch.conf)

Comment: Can you select all DNS traffic in Wireshark or do you have other sources of DNS queries?

Comment: Yes, I can filter all dns queries in Wireshark. The problem being I don't see any of them whem calling dns.lookup. Could it a caching issue ?